# Android Instrumented Layout UI is different than on Debug Build

Tags: android, user-interface

How do I have my instrumented layout (UI) tests that have the same style and theme as my debug build?

Currently, the layout that's displayed when I open the Fragment from the Instrumented test is different style-wise from the Fragment when opened when using the application normally.

Am I missing a core step in writing instrumented tests in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, you can specify a Theme attribute in the `launchFragmentInContainer` method.

```
val fragment = ShippingAddressInputFragment.newInstance(vmStore())
launchFragmentInContainer(
  themeResId = R.style.AppTheme,
  instantiate = { fragment }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your answer use [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) as your question isn't very specific.